# How to add MVC 6 reference to a class library to extend some stuff?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've started dealing with ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 in the past week, and I'm still feeling that I'm in a bad nightmare time to time.

I previously had a nice class library which had a reference to MVC 5 (via Nuget), and there I've implemented several extensions, mods for MVC like custom model binder, several custom attributes, filters, HTML helpers, etc.

Now I thought I will simply update to MVC 6, but I was naively wrong. The following happens:

1. The project targets .NET 4.5.1.
2. I start installing MVC 6 via PM console.
3. It starts to install a giant bunch of packages (!).
4. After 1-2 minutes I get an error:

   Failed to add reference to 'System.IO'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.
5. OK, no panic, I've found an article when one suggested adding manually a reference to the `System.IO` "thing" in the project file. I wrote "thing" because I don't quite understand what actually it is. It should normally be just a namespace inside the `System` core. So I've added the reference manually, and after reloading the project I can see a nice exclamation mark in the references list next to it. But OK, let's try again.
6. After trying again, I again get an error, now missing `System.Runtime`. I do the same, goto step 5. Then it misses `System.Collections`... and now I'm here because I'm getting mad.

Why is it so hard to have a simple pure class library for extensions to MVC?

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is wrong because `System.IO` and `System.Runtime` are not in the GAC. The error got addressed [here](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CReference%20Assemblies%5CMicrosoft%5CFramework%5C.NETFramework%5Cv4.5.1%5CFacades) and should not occur any more after RC1. If you are still using RC1 you can reference those two dlls manually before installing the nuget packages. They can be found in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades`

The dlls will be shown with a yellow triangle in Visual Studio but the packages can be installed successfully.